# How to set directory permission in linux which prevents users (except owner) to delete file but allow them to modify content?

Tags: permissions, samba

Environment : 
Server - Ubuntu (as of now ver 13)
Clients - Windows 8 boxes

We are setting up Samba-NAS box running ubuntu in office, there is one requirement by team to set following system.
1. Owner will place file in folder which can be deleted by owner only.
2. Other users can modify content of directory (actually process owned by other users on windows desktop will access this files and modify its content).  But they should be able to delete it.

I explored chattr and sticky bit, but could not find combination to make it work.

The drives are where files will be created/edited are on non-root drives and will be mounted on mnt/disk directory.

Answer (score 1):

I would  fiddle with idea of "Creator Owner" vs "other users" permissions and instead of files permissions in some folder go for Creator Owned folders/dirs and perhaps create different "exchange" files some readable, some writable. This depends on what you actually want to achieve.

SElinux may help too, but it seems that combination of SElinux and Samba would rise more questions than solve them. Rock-bottom: applying more rules create more quirks one could easily overlook.

My experience with this kind of problems shows that if you need more fine-grained access than OS/File System allows you to do it is often wiser to think of a custom security model and write an application that has access system you need. Perhaps use databases.

I am also curious if someone else resolved this problem in some acceptable way and if s/he did what would be conceptual boundaries.

here is a question that would bother me: if someone else can edit my file (effectively being able to delete whole content) - what would be difference between this and actually deleting a file?

Comment: I believe file is going to be modified by process not individual.  Anyway, its customer requirement and can't argue logic and give them solution if any!

Comment: Tough. You can be as good as your client allows you to be. Guesswork - legacy application (not modifiable) that may have quirks so file system shall act as protection. Last known (to me) system that had this kind of fine grade access control (control of each file function individually) was novell.

Comment: Your problem may be resolved likely by manually giving rights for each user file (creator owner = full control, other users=read/write) read/write permission in windows shall not allow deletion of the file (samba shall copy that). Another guesswork - that is probably not desirable as I guess you'd like this (complex access rights) to be automatically done during file creation.

Comment: other users can inherit folder rights.